# SonarQube rule SingularField (S1450) and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, sonarqube

SonarQube 6 marks variables injected by DI into my constructor as a critical rule violation. Since we use constructor injection on all our classes for their dependencies, this rule does not make any sense for fields set by the constructor. I could deactivate the rule but then I would miss all the relevant methods where it really could be an issue.

Does anyone has a solution or an idea how to handle that problem? 
[This is the rule documentation](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS1450).

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IRequestMapper _requestMapper;
    private readonly IResponseMapper _responseMapper;

    public SomeService(IRequestMapper requestMapper, IResponseMapper responseMapper)
    {
        this._requestMapper = requestMapper;
        this._responseMapper = responseMapper;
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        // only if you don't use the dependencies, you get the the SonarQube error
        return "nothing";
    }
}

public interface IResponseMapper
{
    string MapResponse(string response);
}

public interface IRequestMapper
{
    string CreateRequest();
}
```

[image: SonarQube Screenshot]

Comment: The rule makes sense, but if it detects constructor dependencies as violations, IMO its implementation is seriously broken. My advice: exclude this rule (since it is useless in its current form) and report a bug with SonarQube.

Comment: @Eulinky are you sure about the link to the SQ rule? This is the java rule, and I think your issue is related to the c# implementation [csharpsquid:S1450](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS1450)?

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for your opinion!

Comment: @Michael: Right, sorry - C# is meant. Since you seem to be part of the Sonar Source Team - would you consider that a bug?

Comment: @Eulinky I can't yet repro your issue. Could you edit your question with a code fragment that compiles? Right now you have `MyClass` with a constructor `SomeFactory`, and also `DoSomething` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Tamas: You're right, this issues only comes up if the dependencies aren't used somewhere in the class. If I use them in the GetString() method, the warning goes away. Didn't check that, sorry!

Comment: I get the S1450 when I inject an item that is not used by the constructor itself, but only stored as reference. I use this reference in a private function that is called by a public function, so it is a useless warning

Comment: Possible related: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/182